# Angular Material SnackBar and custom ErrorHandler to notify error

Tags: angular, error-handling, angular-material, snackbar

I have an error custom handler class that implements ErrorHandler of Angular 5 core. If an error occours, handleError method have to notify it sending a snackbar material component that show up.
If the error is thrown in a test button, all be fine.

If the error occours on the method ngOnInit, the snackbar doesn't work properly and it show up in a position wrong of the page and you can't dismiss it anymore.

I.E.

My Component:

```
export class RootPageComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() {}

    public buttonTest() {
        it.happens;
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        it.happens;
    }
}
```

This is my custom error handler:

```
export class ErrorHandlerCustom extends ErrorHandler {

    constructor(...){}
    handleError() {
        const notificationService = this.injector.get(NotificationService);
        // notification custom using snackbar material
        notificationService.exceptionError(error);
    }
}
```

Results with error in ngOnInit:
[ngOnInit error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVosE.png)

Click on test button:
[click on test button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEeGv.png)

Comment: Please include the code of what you have already tried. We can’t guess what’s your current implementation to figure out the error

Comment: i recoomend you to use https://stackblitz.com/ for demostration of your isuue

Comment: Please include your code on the **question** itself. Using images is a bad idea since the website could no longer exist, your question can't be searchable since images aren't text and those with poor internet will have to wait for a while just to load the image.

Comment: Thanks for adding your solution. Instead of editing your question, just post it as an answer and mark it as a solution. This way other users will know that your question was resolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have finally figured out the problem. I don't know if this is the correct way.

In a lot of cases the error handler will run outside of Angular's zone. This causes toasts not to behave correctly since change detection doesn't run on it. So it is necessary to use zone in properly run.

```
    this.zone.run(() => {
        this.snackBar.open(message, "UNDO");
    }
```

Here I found my solution and I post it just in case someone else encountered the same problem:
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9875

Comment: Here this causes the error to continuously get thrown in some cases (e.g. in the case of a template error). Don't find solution for this. More info: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17010 / https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/16426 / https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7233

Answer (score 4):

In my case, The solution was using `this.handleError.bind(this)` as shown below:

```
  public post<T>(url: string, data: any, options?: HttpOptions): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.post<T>(this.baseUrl + url, data, options).pipe(
      map((res: T) => {
        return res as T;
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError.bind(this))
    );
```

Comment: This one was the solution for me, since I also had the issue in handleError function with pipe. Thanks!